# Why cents for std::put_money()?

Tags: c++, locale, money-format

I'm wondering why the `std::put_money()` function accepts cents instead of dollars. Also [looking at the definition on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/money_put), it does not say what the input number should be.

Is it true that whatever the currency we have to use a decimal number at the lowest possible decimal value of said currency? (i.e. so `* 1.0`, `* 100.0`, or `* 1000.0` as the case may be?) Because that seems to incorporate knowledge of the currency opposed to the current locale...

Comment: That's documentation for `std::money_put`. [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money) is documentation for `std::put_money`

Comment: @FredLarson Except it [does use `long double` to represent currency](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money). You either pass in a `long double` or a `basic_string`

Comment: @Justin: Well, that's unfortunate.

Comment: Well, using (`long`) `double` for dollars is a bad idea, using it for cents is generally fine - integers are represented perfectly by `double`, and up to not so distant times `double` was the best fundamental type to represent exactly fairly big integers (when your `long` is 32 bit and you don't have bigger integers 53 bits of mantissa aren't something to waste).

Comment: It looks like this part of the C++ standard library is just not very well documented on cppreference. Might be a good idea to consult the standard directly (http://eel.is/c++draft/category.monetary), and update cppreference with what is found (it's a wiki)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I think that would be at least the start of a decent answer.

Comment: @Justin: TBH, I'm not surprised - C and C++ locales are a broken, complex mess which falls short of any reasonable expectation, and money formatting is probably the most useless of their features; I never had or wrote a program which had to display money values "in general", whatever currency is set up systemwide.

Comment: @FredLarson: unfortunately, I don't know enough about locales (and their history) to answer satisfactorily; I'd have to do some research but I'm not sure I have enough time now.

Comment: ["The currency units are assumed to be the smallest non-fractional units of the currency: cents in the U.S, yen in Japan."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/money_put/put#Notes)

Comment: [I think this results from watching Superman III as a child.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salami_slicing)

Comment: @Justin, that link is definitely the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

The general idea is that you don't want to use floating point with currency, because values with a finite number of decimal digits can be periodic in binary, and given that floating point values have finite precision this leads to surprises when summing them; the usual example is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double v = 0.;
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) v+=0.1;
    printf("%0.18g\n", v-1.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

which prints `-1.11022302462515654e-16`.

---

A simple approach to deal with the problem is to use integral values for ["the smallest non-fractional units of the currency"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/money_put/put#Notes) (thanks @Justin for the quote); this makes sure that when the user inputs $ 0.10 it's exactly represented, and does not lead to any rounding surprise, at least as long as we are dealing with values where exact precision is expected.

This is fine and explains the cents, but why `long double` and not some integral type? Here I'm speculating, but I see two reasonable motivations:

- fractional amounts of currency are something that exists, typically for unitary prices (e.g. the price per liter of gasoline); the precision there is generally less of an issue - you are going to multiply it by another floating point value anyway - but you want to be able to read such values;
- but most importantly, historically floating point values had the best precision over a wide spectrum of platforms, even for integral values. `long long` (guaranteed to be at least 64 bit) is a recent addition to the standard, and `long` was generally 32 bit wide: it would have capped monetary values to a meager ~21 million dollars.

  OTOH, even a plain `double` on most platforms has a 53 digits mantissa, which means that it can represent exactly integral values up to 9007199254740991 - so, something like 90 thousand billion dollars; that's good enough to represent exactly the US public debt down to cents, so it's probably precise enough for pretty much anything else. They probably chose *`long`* `double`  as "the biggest hammer they can throw at the problem" (even if nowadays it's generally as big as a plain `double`).

> Because that seems to incorporate knowledge of the currency opposed to the current locale...

Yes and no; I think that the idea was that, as long as you use the relevant locale facets both for input and for output, you simply shouldn't really care - the library should do the conversions for you, and you just work with numbers whose exact magnitude shouldn't really matter to you.

---

That's the theory; but as said in the comments, C and C++ locales are a badly designed piece of software, with an overly complicated design which however falls short when tested for real-world usage.

Honestly, I would never use this stuff "for real":

- you can never be sure of how updated the standard library is, how broken it is (I once had VC++ not being able to do a roundtrip of Italian-localized numbers), if it actually supports the currencies you care about.
- you *do* need to care about what is its idea of "smallest non-fractional unit of the currency" if you need to talk with anything besides textual IO in the format expected by the library - say, you have to get the price of a stock from a web service, or if you have built-in data to combine with the user input;
- same for serialization in a machine readable format; you don't want to expose yourself to the vagaries of your C runtime and of OS configuration when storing the user data, especially if they are to be exchanged with other applications, especially if said applications run on a different C runtime (it may even be your own application compiled for a different operating system!) or a different language.

Comment: Oh, I know that any currency number should only use integers. I have a hard time to understand why most people don't know that. I was just super surprised that C++ would do something like that. Cool.